# Getting '424' on ActiveWorkSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a Run-time error '424': Object required on line `ActiveWorkSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear` in the following code:

```
Sub UpdateCharts()
'
' UpdateCharts Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+u
'
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    For iIndex = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set ws = Worksheets(iIndex)
        ws.Activate
        Range("AQ6:AS19").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("T6:V19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveWorkSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            "V6:V19"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkSheet.Sort
            .SetRange Range("T6:V19")
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        Range("W5") = "=Today()"
        Range("V5").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("W5").Clear
        Range("A1").Select
    Next iIndex
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Activesheet, use ws

this is cleaned up a bit, showing how to use `with ws`

```
Sub Button1_Click()


    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    For iIndex = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set ws = Worksheets(iIndex)
        With ws
            .Range("AQ6:AS19").Copy
            .Range("T6:V19").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range( _
                                      "V6:V19"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
                                 xlSortNormal
            With .Sort
                .SetRange Range("T6:V19")
                .Header = xlGuess
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
            .Range("W5") = "=Today()"
            'Range("V5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' you have nothing copied
            .Range("W5").Clear
            '            .Range("A1").Select'don't select A1
        End With

    Next iIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works like a charm.  I would like to make cell A1 the active cell in each processed worksheet, but {.Range("A1").Select} throws an error, which is likely why you said not to do it.  How can I do this?